# vps (just host) max execution time is not working

Tags: php, vps

I have bought vps. Configured "max_execution_time" to 6000 from whm as per support team.

But no script is running more than 80 to 90 seconds. I have tried to get it resolve with vps support team but they are not helping me as max execution time is showing 6000. Restarted(force) the server also many times but no change.

For trouble shouting I have written `sleep(0)` only in a PHP page but it is
also throwing the 500 internal error.

Can any one help me to get it resolved?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't buy a VPS you hired it, besides you should solve this with your VPS provider.

Comment: Why don't you set max_execution_time to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, already done but not working.

Comment: 2 process I have used set_time_limit(0) , & ini_set('max_execution_time', 6000);

Comment: Have you verified it's the correct config that you're changing? What does `phpinfo()` tell you?

Comment: Please check from http://access-electronic.co.uk/phpinfo.php

Comment: However this defines how long the PHP can execute without timing out - not *necessarily* how long the webserver will wait for PHP to respond. Check your webserver config for a timeout.

Comment: Hi,  h2ooooooo, can you tell me from where this nee to be change/check ?

Answer (score 0):

It can also be an memory issue with your VPS server, Or it can even be due to overloading on the node your VPS is on.

Comment: I have checked this also, changed memory limit but not worked